# How to use JSP tags in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jsp

How to use JSP tags in JavaScript file?

Is there any way?

Answer (score 5):

JSP is a view technology which runs at the server side which you can use to write template text like HTML/CSS/JS in. You can use JSP taglibs and EL to control the page flow and output dynamically using Java code. This also concerns the JavaScript content/output. Once JSP has run, it basically produces a HTML page and sends it to the client side. You can use JSP to dynamically output back-end data as if it are JavaScript variables. For example:

```
<script>
    var foo = '${someBean.someProperty}';
</script>
```

Once the HTML page (with CSS/JS inside) has arrived at the client side (rightclick page and view source, you won't see any line of Java/JSP code), then the HTML will start to be interpreted, the CSS will start to be applied and the JS will start to be executed. There's no means of Java/JSP code at the client side. If you view the generated source in the client, the above example would now look like:

```
<script>
    var foo = 'somePropertyValue';
</script>
```

This way JavaScript has just instant access to server-side variables.

Now the other way round; the only way to let JavaScript access/invoke Java/JSP code is to *actually* send a HTTP request to the server side. This can be done several ways: doing a `window.location` to do a synchronous GET request, or doing a `form.submit()` to do a synchronous GET or POST request, or doing a `XMLHttpRequest#send()` to do an asynchronous request (also known from Ajax).

Alternatively you can also just let JavaScript set a (hidden) input field of a form so that it "automatically" get taken with the form submit whenever the user submits the form. Either way, the Java/JSP code at the server side will then be able to access JavaScript-controlled values the usual request parameter way.

To learn more about the wall between Java/JSP and JavaScript you may find [this article](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/javajspjsf-and-javascript.html) useful.

Comment: Hi, I am storing some important data in the JS variables via JSP tag libs and use them to render in the frontend. I have around 100 variables assigned via JSP taglibs. But when I use, "View Source" all the variables are like the declaration, is there any way to hide it from the view but use the variable for rendering

Answer (score 2):

I have wondered about this when I have values in my session or context I wanted exposed in the client side. I create a jsp file with javascript mime type which just include global variable values. Which  I then include at the top of my page and reuse the values where necessary.

for eg:

```
**globalVar.jsp** 

var ctxPath = "<%=request.getContextPath()%>";

**script.js**

ajaxURL = ctxPath + "/path/to/call?param=value";
```

You can even namespace this as [outlined here](http://www.dustindiaz.com/namespace-your-javascript/)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use JSP to generate JavaScript to send to the browser. Just point the `<script>` tag to a URL that leads to a JSP page that sets the MIME type of the response to "text/javascript".

No, you cannot use JSP tags in JavaScript in the browser. JSP is a server-side technology, which means that processing must be done on the server.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily use java tags to assign to a java variable which is later invoked inside the javascript code.

`<% String name="Peter" %>`

and then in javascript..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

var _name = <%= name %>

Answer (score 1):

@BalusC answer explain's well what is server-side and client-side programming. However I would like to highlight a point that if you really want to get run `jsp` within your `javascript`, then you can give it file extension `.jsp` instead of `.js` because what determines whether a file is a `javascript` file or not is what MIME media type. You can set MIME from JSP using:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/javascript" %>
```

and now you can use `jsp` within your `javascript` like:

```
var someMessage = "${someMessage}"
var anotherMessage = "${anotherMessage}"/>"
```

and now, you can link directly to it as:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/script.jsp"></script>
```